# What is the hierarchy of classes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

Could anyone point to a reliable model of the JavaScript standard class/prototype cloning inheritance relations?

The "standard prototypes" I refer to are window, navigator, document, and so forth and so on.

Comment: There are no classes and therefore no class inheritance in JavaScript.

Comment: @Radu I disagree prototypal inheritance yes, classical inheritance no.

Comment: @JonH, you're right, made the comment more explicit.

Comment: The OP *did* say 'class/prototype', which I think is intended to show he is uncertain of the terms and form of inheritance, thus the question.

Comment: I know that javascript is a prototype based language, but at the root of prototypes are classes. The difference is that classes are inherited and prototypes are strictly cloned.

Comment: @AndrewG.H., what do you mean by "at the root of prototypes are classes"?

Comment: `[(User defined) constructor instance] > [(User defined) constructor] > Function > Object` - Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: @Radu Well as we all know, class-based models use collections of data representations to create instances of objects that carry the data. In the prototype model the prototypes("classes") carry the data in a static manner, just like the static methods/attributes of the normal OOP model.

Comment: @(Rob W) no, I'm intrested in the standard/public ones, that everyone use when they code in javascript. (window, navigator, document, etc). Something that would resemble the "UML model" of JavaScript if I might say.

Comment: @AndrewG.H. open the console, type `window`, (scroll all the way down, expand `__proto__`) <- repeat. Most of this stuff has a very short chain before it hits `Object`. `document` and other nodes have longer chains in webkit (and moz I think), try `dir(document)`.

Comment: I'm disappointed. No one pointed to [W3schools DOM Reference](http://w3schools.com/jsref/) page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to the DOM objects provided by browsers, take a look at [Mozilla's Gecko DOM reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference). Each browser however provides their own native objects though, so you should verify that a certain object is indeed available and works similarly in all the browsers that you want to target.

Comment: I guess the emphasis was more on "document, and so forth and so on" than "window" and "navigator"

Answer (score 0):

this is a pretty good one.

http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html

As @Radu and @johnH pointed out, there's no "classes" per se, but there *is* a sort of inheritance through the prototype.